# understanding cuboc libgdx example

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have cloned and was able to produce a functional application from the Cuboc libgdx demo I got from here: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx-demo-cuboc

I am trying to understand this bit of code in the Cuboc libgdx demo.  I will add my questions as comments in the code below:

```
package com.badlogic.cubocy;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array;

public class Map {
    static int EMPTY = 0;
    /***
     ***  why do these ints have to be in hex ?
     ***/
    static int TILE = 0xffffff;
    static int START = 0xff0000;
    static int END = 0xff00ff;
    static int DISPENSER = 0xff0100;
    static int SPIKES = 0x00ff00;
    static int ROCKET = 0x0000ff;

    ...

    private void loadBinary () {
        /***
         *** how did the file "levels.png" get created ?
         ***/
        Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(Gdx.files.internal("data/levels.png"));
        tiles = new int[pixmap.getWidth()][pixmap.getHeight()];
        for (int y = 0; y < 35; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < 150; x++) {

                /***
                 *** What's up with the bitwise operations?
                 ***/
                int pix = (pixmap.getPixel(x, y) >>> 8) & 0xffffff;
                if (match(pix, START)) {
                ...
                } else if (match(pix, DISPENSER)) {
                ...
                } else if (match(pix, ROCKET)) {
                ...                 
                } else {
                    tiles[x][y] = pix;
                }
            }
        }

 ...
```

Thanks!

Comment: maybe here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qik60F5I6J4#t=26

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. They don't have to be in hex, but it's a convenient way to see what colors they correspond with in the image file that's being used as a map.
2. The map editor for this game is basically MSPaint. Someone drew the png file in an art program. Each color in the image file matches one of the constant ints at the top of this class.
3. Pixmap ints are in RGBA, but apparently only RGB values are used. If you look at the constant ints at the top, none of them use the first 8 bits of the 32-bit integer. So the bitwise operations on that line drop the A part of the image's pixel (`>>>8`) and gives us an RGB int. I am not super-familiar with bit shifts. It seems redundant to me to mask it with `& 0xffffff` after using an unsigned shift `>>>` instead of a signed shift `>>`, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Just to clarify, Mario mentioned that he used PAINT.NET to do the artwork.